# Responsive text size in tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, size

Could someone let me know which element controls the text size in tables?

I am trying to get a table driven by bootstrap 3 (table.borderless) to be responsive.  So that as the screen shrinks the text within the table reduces in size.

I have managed to get this working with  and normal elements of HTML, but its not 'shrinking' the table text for some reason....

I have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` line in there to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added,

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    html { font-size: 0.7rem; }
    th { font-size: 1rem; }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html { font-size: 0.8rem; }
    th { font-size: 1rem; }

}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    html { font-size: 0.8rem; }
    th { font-size: 1rem; }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 0.8rem; }
    th { font-size: 1rem; }
}
```

Which then obviously makes the whole thing responsive, as long as a number of the other styles are `rem` sized.